# nsis installoptions dropdown onchange event

Tags: installation, nsis, dropdownbox

I want to know how to handle onchange event of dropdown in nsis installoptions .

Actually what I want to do is based on selection made on dropdown some text fileds should be polulated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#step-notify

Alternatively, could you move the dependent text fields onto the next page?